# How to create a dnf module outside fedora build system?

Tags: module, fedora, rpm, centos8, dnf

How to create a dnf module outside fedora build system?

I want to create my private module/stream without fedora build system. 
I have read the document at https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/modularity/making-modules/defining-modules/ .

But I do not get any information about how to create a module outside fedora.

Createrepo also do not give any information about module.

Do I need to write the whole modulemd.yaml hand by hand?
If I have 2 modules in one repo, just concat the 2 modulemd.yaml?